# Why is there an error message when I run a weighted logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

While performing a weighted logistic regression I got the error "notice! number of non-integer successes in a binomial glm" Why is this happening?

```
model<- glm(outcome~treatment, weights=weight, data=mydata, family=binomial(link=log))
betaiptw<- coef(model)
SE<- sqrt(diag(vcovHC(model, type ="HC0")))
rr<- exp(betaiptw[2])
lcl<- exp(betaiptw[2] -1.96*SE[2])
ucl<- exp(betaiptw[2] +1.96*SE[2])
c(lcl, rr, ucl)
```

I didn't expect the error message.

Comment: That's the error you might get if `outcome` is not purely 1s and 0s

Comment: see e.g. `unique(mydata$outcome)`.

Comment: The outcome is purely 1s and 0s.

Comment: In another thread, a user mentioned that the warning was just "glm being silly" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078497/weighted-logistic-regression-in-r. Can anyone confirm why this error is occurring? Should I be worried about it or nah?